# Securing Oauth2 refresh_token

Tags: security, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Oauth2 to handle authentication in my system. While the authentication works, I'm worried about the security of my refresh token endpoint. The front-end calls this endpoint to get a new access token after it expires.

My question is how would you prevent someone from calling that endpoint and getting a new access token? Would you use the access token to authenticate yourself? At the moment I'm using these tokens to authenticate API calls on a separate service.

The endpoint currently supports csrf, but that's probably not enough.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token is used to get the new access token.  That is where the authentication happens.

You can decrease the time that a refresh token is valid.

You can also choose if you want the refresh token to be renewed or not with each call to refresh the access token.

Unauthenticated clients cannot call the refresh token endpoint and get a new access token.

Comment: I understand, but how would you authenticate these clients in the first place?

Comment: You are only providing access+refresh tokens to clients that you have authenticated right?  I assumed from your question that you were already authenticating clients successfully.

Comment: Yes I'm authenticating the client by the username/password to the authorization server, which returns the 2 tokens. The client keeps the refresh token in a db. I have an endpoint on the client, that fetches the refresh token and sends it to the authorization server to get back a new access_token. This is the endpoint I'm referring to, how do I make sure a user, who is already logged in, can't make an ajax request and get an access token for a different user?

Comment: All you need to do is make sure that "bad user" can't get access to another user's refresh_token.  If bad_user asks for a new access_token, using his refresh_token, he will only be able to get a new access_token for bad_user.